# Docker Compose - adding volume using Amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose v2 to build my containers (Django and Nginx).

I'm wondering how to store the static and media files. At the beginning I stored them as a volume on the machine, but the machine crashed and I lost the data (or at least, I didn't know how to recover it).
I thought it's better to store it on Amazon S3, but there are no guides for that (maybe it means something :) ).

This is my docker-compose file:
I tried to add the the needed fields (name, key, secret,...) but no success so far.

Is it the right way?
Thanks!

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./web:/code
      - static-data:/www/static
      - media-data:/www/media
    env_file: devEnv

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - static-data:/www/static
      - media-data:/www/media
    volumes_from:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web


volumes:
  static-data:
    driver: local
  media-data:
    driver: s3
```

Comment: See django-storages

Answer (score 1):

Here a example of how upload files to S3(for backup) from a container, but would be made in the host OS too, since you have a volume of container mounted on Host OS. 
In this script I download media from S3 to a local container/server. After it, I use `pynotify` to watch the dir `static/media`, for modifications. If any change occur it upload the file to S3 using the command `subprocess.Popen(upload_command.split(" "))`. 
I think that you can adapt this script for your problem too.
Before you test this script, you should set your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` on the environment variables of OS.

For more details [S4cmd documentation](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd).

```
#!-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import pyinotify
import os
import subprocess
from single_process import single_process

# You most have set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
# in enviromnet variables

PROJECT_DIR = os.getcwd()
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static/media")

AWS_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_BUCKET_NAME", '')

S4CMD_DOWNLOAD_MEDIA = "s4cmd get --sync-check --recursive s3://%s/static/media/ static/" % (AWS_BUCKET_NAME)
UPLOAD_FILE_TO_S3="s4cmd sync --sync-check %(absolute_file_dir)s s3://"+ AWS_BUCKET_NAME +"/%(relative_file_dir)s"

# Download all media from S3
subprocess.Popen(S4CMD_DOWNLOAD_MEDIA.split(" ")).wait()

class ModificationsHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        try:
            dir = event.path
            file_name = event.name

            absolute_file_dir=os.path.join(dir, file_name)
            relative_dir=dir.replace(PROJECT_DIR, "")
            relative_file_dir=os.path.join(relative_dir, file_name)

            if relative_file_dir.startswith("/"):
                relative_file_dir = relative_file_dir[1:]

            print("\nSeding file %s to S3" % absolute_file_dir)

            param = {}
            param.update(absolute_file_dir=absolute_file_dir)
            param.update(relative_file_dir=relative_file_dir)         

            upload_command = UPLOAD_FILE_TO_S3 % param
            print(upload_command)
            subprocess.Popen(upload_command.split(" "))
        except Exception as e:
            # log excptions
            print("Some problem:", e.message)

@single_process
def main():
    handler = ModificationsHandler()
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
    print("\nListening changes in: " + MEDIA_DIR)
    if MEDIA_DIR:
        wdd = wm.add_watch(MEDIA_DIR, pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE, auto_add=True, rec=True)
        notifier.loop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You just backup the files to s3, right? Why is it better than using the S3 itself to serve the files? Thanks!

Comment: No, I doesn’t only backup, also serve files from S3 to clients. I must have the files on disk because `mezzanine` framework don't work very well. My initial problem was the integration of `mezzanine` with S3, then this was the solution.

Comment: I thought to define the s3 bucket as volume in the docker, so it suppose to be transparent to django where the files are actually saved.

Comment: In one way, or another, the files should be synchronized with S3. It's one possible way. But, it's transparent for the Django. I start this script as a worker. Django only upload the media for `static/media` dir, then the script upload the files to S3 automatically.

Comment: I ended up uploading the files directly to S3 without backup using django-storages and using CDN for user requests

Comment: Great solution! I my case can't do it as mentioned.